# OS.REMOVE not quite working right

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a PDF generation program. One feature is to merge all pdfs and delete all the pieces after. I have it working perfectly until I changed the path to the pdfs. Here is the function:

```
def pdf_cleanup(name):
    files_dir = '/root/PycharmProjects/ReportApp/FML/Pdf_Docs'

    xx = [f for f in os.listdir(files_dir) if f.endswith("pdf")]

    for f in xx:
        if f.startswith(name):
            pass
        else:
            os.remove(f)
    return
```

Looking at the `files_dir` variable if I set it back one directory - so it looks like this `files_dir = '/root/PycharmProjects/ReportApp/FML'` Than it works fine. When I try to use it in the Pdf_Docs directory I error out saying that 'name_of_pdf' does not exist, when it does.

Traceback:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /root/PycharmProjects/ReportApp/FML/dump.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/ReportApp/FML/dump.py", line 16, in <module>
    pdf_cleanup('mer')
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/ReportApp/FML/dump.py", line 13, in pdf_cleanup
    os.remove(f)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Main_Calls.pdf'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is there something stupid and small I am overlooking?? I don't understand why changing one folder breaks it.

Comment: It looks like you are not using the new location try `os.remove(files_dir + '/' +f)`

Comment: `os.listdir(files_dir)` returns a list of the filenames + extensions. As such it works if the files are in the same directory as the executable. As such, instead you should call `os.remove(os.path.join(files_dir, f))` to join the path and the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.listdir()` will only give you the files names, not their path, ie:

```
>>> files_dir = "/home/bruno/Work/blookup/src/project/blookcore"
>>> [f for f in os.listdir(files_dir) if f.endswith(".py")]
['tasks.py', 'posts.py', 'models.py', '__init__.py', 'signals.py', 'urls.py', 'utils.py', 'translation.py', 'views.py', 'forms.py', 'fields.py', 'storages.py', 'admin.py', 'managers.py']
```

So when you call `os.remove()` on one of the files names, it looks for for this file in the current working directory, not in `files_dir`.

The solution is plain and simple: join `files_dir` and `f` to get the full path:

```
 os.remove(os.path.join(files_dir, f))
```

As a side note: you have one test in the list comprehension and another in the for loop. You could as well put both in the list comp:

```
xx = [
    f for f in os.listdir(files_dir) 
    if f.endswith("pdf") and not f.startswith(name)
    ]

for f in xx:
    os.remove(os.path.join(files_dir, f))
```

Answer (score 0):

`xx` is a list of file names, not file paths. Merge the path with the directory like so: `os.remove(os.path.join(files_dir, f))`